# Mapping methodology and/or clustering technique needed

Tags: cartography, clustering

I have a scenario in which I have two service centers (A & B) in an area. The capacity of these service centers are different. Service Center A can serve twice as many as Service Center B.

They both are servicing in the same area. The issue is I want exclusive servicing. Meaning the locations Service Center A services cannot be the same as those Service Center B services. Priority would be distance from centers, however because of capacity restraints I understand Service Center A may have to go to locations technically closer to Service Center B.

Is there a particular type of analysis I should begin to explore?

I feel like K-Means almost took me there, but those results generated my service centers as seeds and my serviceable locations (observations) in terms of proximity only and clustered from there.

Comment: I'd define n/3 customers closest to fascilty with smaller capcity, where n is total number of customers. The rest of customers will have to use 2nd fascility

Comment: Voronoi polygons would also be a good starting point.

Comment: Perhaps providing more details about what you have already tried, and what you found to be its shortcomings may trigger potential answerers to try and do so.

Comment: I found the perfect tool.  ArcGis- Network Analyst - Capacitated Coverage http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/location-allocation.htm